# Unbound Integer Class

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am implementng an UnboundInteger class which behaves as regular integers.
The idea is to be able to do operations over arbitrarily large
integers which do not have any limits on either side as to the
supported size.

Here is my code

```
class UnboundInteger(object):

def __init__(self, integer):
    self.integer = str(integer)


def __add__(self, other):
    carry = '0'
    temp = '0'
    result = ''

    if (len(self.integer) > len(other.integer)):
        num_of_zeros = len(self.integer) - len(other.integer)
        other.integer = '0' * num_of_zeros + other.integer

    elif (len(self.integer < other.integer)):
        num_of_zeros = len(other.integer) - len(self.integer)
        self.integer = '0' * num_of_zeros + self.integer

    for i in range(1, len(self.integer)+1):
        temp = str(int(self.integer[-i]) + int(other.integer[-i]) + int(carry))
        temp = '0' + temp
        temp = temp[-1]
        carry = temp[-2]
        result = temp + result

    return UnboundInteger(result)



@classmethod
def from_int(cls, integer):
    '''\
    Take in a integer and build the unbound integer object.
    '''
    ub_integer = cls(integer)
    return ub_integer
```

Unfortunately I am unable to debug the error
Please help me out

Here is the error

```
    In [40]: reload(test)
Out[40]: <module 'test' from 'test.py'>

In [41]: a = test.UnboundInteger(1000000000000)

In [42]: b = test.UnboundInteger(20000000000)

In [43]: a + b
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-f96fb8f649b6> in <module>()
----> 1 a + b

/home/neel101/test.py in __add__(self, other)
     17             temp = '0' + temp
     18             temp = temp[-1]
---> 19             carry = temp[-2]
     20             result = temp + result
     21 

IndexError: string index out of range
```

Or any better approach for this problem. Please let me know!

Comment: out of curiosity, do you _need_ this for a project or for homework?  If for a project, just use python's `long` type (and usually, `int` will work just fine -- silently converting to `long` when it needs to) ... python3 is even better.  `int` has arbitrary size from the get-go.

Comment: This must be one of those "academic" exercises...

Comment: Yea it is an academic exercise!

Comment: You are assigning last char to temp by temp = temp[-1] and in the next line, you are trying to read last second charater from temp; at this time temp only has last character.

Comment: Thanks! I used temp, carry = temp[-1], temp[-2]

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because you are overwriting temp variable.

```
temp = '0' + temp
temp = temp[-1]
carry = temp[-2]
```

It should be like this:

```
temp = '0' + temp
carry = temp[-2]
temp = temp[-1]
```